# Simulate Workers in SPARK -Java-

Tags: java, apache-spark, apache-spark-sql, bigdata

I was wondering if there is any way to simulate some workers in my local machine, I do know all spark can be set up locally and all can be fully tested. However, I was wondering if it is possible to actually simulate workers, with the idea to see how the repartition of work, loads and the DAG dynamics work.

I also can think about ways that can help me out, for example debugging and tracing data transformations. What I want to do is to develop an optimal way do my program in a testing fashion, I do not wanna rely in the big theory behind shuffling and expensive operations. Or are we dommed to try to test this up in a trial and error in real clusterS? thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Yes, this is possible, please have a look at link https://sparkbyexamples.com/spark/apache-spark-installation-on-windows/

Also, if you can setup spark history server on your local machine, you can trace transformations, DAG etc.